# User has 140GB of archives in outlook

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

I'm a sysadmin, and a user at my job has 140GB of archives in outlook, all of them split up in archives ranging from 2GB to 3GB max.

The problem is that this causes a lot of issues, outlook crashing, dll's not getting registered etc.

The user insists on having all archives linked at all times, unfortunately this user is a higher up and "no" doesn't exist in their vocabulary.

Is there anyone who might have any suggestions on how I could improve his experience.

Extra information

- Outlook 2010 with exchange server
- Archives are stored locally
- 16GB RAM
- not SSD
- windows 7 enterprise

Error messages:

- Cannot move items. The set of folders cannot be opened. Out of memory or system resources.
- OLE registreation error occured (this I can fix temporarily by
  registering the ole DLL).
- Common one: outlook is not responding.

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Comment: There are no tools that exist that can solve this problem.  Having Outlook manage 140GB of emails is beyond the capabilities of it.  This is similar to how Outlook used to not be able handle archive files larger then 4GB.  Even the President of the United States is told, something isn't possible, so best prepare this user for a reality check.  You don't indicate how much system memory, its possible if provided more memory, outlook would behave better.

Comment: I did, the formatting of my post just sucks, for which I apologize, he has 16GB RAM.

Comment: So add more memory to the system.  If you know the format sucks, improve it, because the information is clear as is.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Exchange 2010-2016, then I strongly recommend to utilize its [Online Archiving](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh529934(v=exchg.141).aspx) feature. It just works. The user will get the single additional "Online Archive" storage instead of a bulk of local archives. I personally have ~200GB Online Archive and it works flawless!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to really correct this without changing it up. This person want to be able to search for and get at messages with ease from the archive.  I would recommend looking into using an additional tool and pitching that.

So possibly remove the archive PST files from Outlook and find an offline PST search tool (there are quite a few out there) that he can use locally to search for.

A more advanced option is look at moving to Office 365.  You don't have to move all your mail but with an Exchange plan 2 subscription you can configure a Hybrid setup that will allow you to host archives in Office 365.  With this, the archives sizes are virtually unlimited, and they remain connected to Outlook.  Per the "cache" selection only a subset of the mail is available in the client but the entire archive mailbox remains searchable and messages retrievable from Outlook.  As a side note you would need to upgrade Outlook to 2013 as well.  If you select a subscription level with Office Pro Plus then you can download it from Office 365.

Comment: Storing the emails in the cloud, and allowing to Outlook to cache only what it needs, is a very good idea.  I suspect the real problem might be that current local archives simply need to be compressed, even if that is the case, any problem is going to have problems loading up 140GB of local data.

Comment: Microsoft actually has a service where you can send them your data on a drive and they upload it for you.  That being said the transfer process into O365 works fairly well - you can start and pause it over a few days to move it all up (assuming you stop it during business hours).

Comment: * program not problem.